# How to add a temporary label "new" to a headline wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to have the word "New" put at the beginning of the headline for each new post and have that word stay there for 24hrs, And then after 24hrs it would automatically disappear.

I tried this code but its not working.

```
if (get_the_time() > date("d/m/Y", time()-86400))
{
  echo "New";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to compare **Unix timestamp** with **string** (date() returns string)

```
if((get_the_time('U') + 86400) > time())
       echo 'New'
```